# html table inside form, and getting values with php

Tags: php, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ro">
<head>
        <title>MODIFICA</title>
</head>
<body>
        <?php
        $select1 = isset($_POST['select1']) ? $_POST['select1'] : '';
        if($select1 == 'da'){echo 'ok';}
        else { echo '!ok'; }
        ?>
        <form method="POST">
        <table border="1">
                <thead>
                        <tr>
                                <th>Nume</th>
                                <th>Prenume</th>
                                <th>Adresa</th>
                                <th>Partid</th>
                                <th>Consiliul Local</th>
                                <th>Primar</th>
                                <th>Consiliul Judetean</th>
                                <th>Presedinte Consiliul Judetean</th>
                                <th>Senat</th>
                                <th>Deputat</th>
                                <th>Comisia Europarlamentara</th>
                                <th>Presedinte</th>
                                <th>Submit</th>
                        </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <?php
                        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT nume,prenume,adresa,partid,consiliul_local FROM candidati');
                        $stmt->execute();
                        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)):?>
                        <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $row->nume;?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->prenume;?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->adresa;?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->partid;?></td>
                                <td>
                                        <select name="select1">
                                                 <option value=""></option>
                                                 <option value="<?php echo $row->consiliul_local;?>">
                                                                <?php echo $row->consiliul_local;?>
                                                 </option>
                                        </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                        <select name="select2">
                                                <option value=""></option>
                                                <option value="da">DA</option>
                                        </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                        <select name="select3">
                                                <option value=""></option>
                                                <option value="da">DA</option>
                                        </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                        <select name="select4">
                                                <option value=""></option>
                                                <option value="da">DA</option>
                                        </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                        <select name="select5">
                                                <option value=""></option>
                                                <option value="da">DA</option>
                                        </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                        <select name="select6">
                                                <option value=""></option>
                                                <option value="da">DA</option>
                                        </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                        <select name="select7">
                                                <option value=""></option>
                                                <option value="da">DA</option>
                                        </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                        <select name="select8">
                                                <option value=""></option>
                                                <option value="da">DA</option>
                                        </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                        <button type="submit" name="btn">SUBMIT</button>
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php endwhile;?>
                </tbody>
        </table>
        </form>
</body>
</html
```

I just verify if the $select1 variable is set, and if it's the case, then if the value from "option" (line 44), is 'da', then display it.

The problem that I have is that value is not displayed accordingly. Anyone knows why, and what should I change in order to work?
Or, in simple words, for starting coding the page I need, firstly I just filled-in that "option" tag with the value from db (and yes, the value 'da' is presented in 'consiliul_local' field from db), and then I made a simple echo, above the "form", and if the value of the "select" is 'da', then it should display the message 'ok'. But it always displays the message placed on the else branch. I must specify that I must do the whole logic only with php, and not js or anything else.

Here is how my page looks like, and notice that selected 'da' in the dropdown, which is there because of the MySQL fetch (line 35 in pastebin).
http://www.2shared.com/photo/eXzJ7Glo/1_online.html

This is the page source, which says the value stored in db, is correctly inserted into that value attribute of the  tag.
http://www.2shared.com/uploadComplete.jsp?sId=CACRC8H4n6GrF0jJ

So I select 'da' from that dropdown, then I press the button, and I expect the 'ok' message to be displayed. Any fix? Thanks so much!

Comment: No, even tho I make the same output for select3, the result is the same: "!ok". Now, I didn't filled-up all selects, because all are the same as select1, differs just the column name from db. And the strange thing is that when I do the echo, and I remove all php code, then it displays correctly the message "ok".

Comment: The select input is in a loop you will have tons of selects with the same name.

Comment: PHP retrieves input values based on name attributes. You just make a condition if you are getting information on the same page, throwing the result into the HTML value. I highly recommend using AJAX, if you want to avoid page flashing.

Comment: huh!? I have only 9 selects, and each select have two options: one with empty value attribute, and the other with one value stored in db for that fieldname (here 'consiliul_local'). That's it! And I need, for a short description of the project, to update that value stored in db, through that "select", if a certain php logic is met. Now, at the first step, I just want to fill in that option with the db value, and test to see if it's 'da' then make some specific stuff.

Comment: No, I'm not throwing the result in a HTML value. I take the value ('da') from db, and I put it inside that "option value="DB_VALUE" "/option". Then I test to see if it is 'da', then display 'ok', otherwise display '!ok'. And for some unknown reason, it displays '!ok'. Even if I put an action attribute to the form element, the result is the same. :(